# If one immunosuppresive drug doesn't help with psoriasis, any other immunosupressive won't help with psoriasis, is that correct?

Tags: psoriasis

If one immunosuppressive drug doesn't help with [psoriasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psoriasis), any other immunosuppressive won't help with psoriasis, is that correct?

For example, if [methotrexate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methotrexate) doesn't help with psoriasis, is it true that other immunosuppressive drugs such as [ciclosporin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciclosporin) or [apremilast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apremilast), and others won't help with this psoriasis?

Comment: Your question is exactly equivalent to, "If amoxicillin+clavulanic acid doesn't eradicate an infection, neither will ciprofloxin or azithromycin, is that correct?" If you know the answer to that, you know the answer to your question.